# Pandas: Unexpected Behavior From Boolean Mask on Dataframe using another Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, filter

**Problem**: Attempting to filter one dataframe using a mask that compares its index to the index of another dataframe. I've created a boolean mask, but my attempts return only an empty dataset.

**Question:** Is there a way to mask using indexes, or perhaps by converting the indexes to columns and comparing the dataframes?

The mask looks like:

```
my_towns.set_index(['State', 'RegionName'], inplace=True)
index1 = my_towns.index
index2 = qtr_data.index
qtr_data[qtr_data.index.isin(my_towns.index)]
```

The result is an empty dataframe.

Test datasets [my_towns](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6ymLohJIbhCNDFHRnhBdWRzaW8) and [qtr_data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6ymLohJIbhCcnRnTzZzQnhVa2s). These dfs both have multi-index. A simple example could be created from the example below following the masking steps above, i.e, use df2.index as a filter on df1's rows.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'State' : ['Hawaii', 'Alabama', 'California', 'Washington'], 'Region' : ['Honolulu', 'Mobile', 'Los Angeles', 'Spokane'], '2001q1' : ['123','345','456','567']}).set_index(['State','Region'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'State' : ['Alabama', 'California', 'Washington'], 'Region' : ['Mobile', 'Los Angeles', 'Spokane']}).set_index(['State', 'Region'])
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text.  And read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Thanks @JohnZwinck. Example datasets forthcoming.

Comment: This seems to work fine with your example data? `df1[df1.index.isin(df2.index)]` produces the expected result for me.

Comment: Thank for testing on the simple example I published, @root. Though, if I try that exact recipe on the actual test datasets, I get an empty dataframe returned, which shouldn't be the case. Any ideas?

Comment: You can also try `df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(df2.index)]`. But it looks to me like that intersection is empty and because of this you are getting empty data set